# JIRA + Bitbucket - Update a file after a JIRA ticket has transitioned

Tags: bitbucket, jira, changelog

Is there way where I can have a file in my repo appended with the name and description of a Jira ticket, when the ticket is transitioned to a specific stage.

For example, if my ticket `API-1234: Do some work` is moved to the stage `Ready to Deploy`, this line is added to the top of a file 'changelog.md' in my repo: `API-1234: Do some work`.

I understand there can be caveats to this, like what if the ticket is moved back to a different stage etc, but just wondering about this basic implementation. I have JIRA integrated with Bitbucket, but can't find any resource on if this specific ask is possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more complex than just using the Jira Automation tool.
As i see you will need to create a CI pipeline that creates a file when a certain rule has passed (in your case, an issue has been transitioned).

In this case you can use the webhook function in the Jira Automation.